# How to detect the Javascript injected suspicious file in my wordpress post?

Tags: wordpress, malware-detection

Detected potentially suspicious content from the website malware scanner. It showing some code from the scan results:https://scanner.pcrisk.com/detailed_report/pragmaticwebmedia.com#details

But unable to find the script on my site. How to delete the dump code in the above results?

I just tried website scanner and cpanel scan but none helps.

[[   window._wpemojiSettings = { "baseUrl":"https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11.2.0/72x72/","ext":".png","svgUrl":"https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11.2.0/svg/","svgExt":".svg","source": { "concatemoji":"https://pragmaticwebmedia.com/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.1.1" }  };  !function(a,b,c) { function d(a,b) { var c=String.fromCharCode; l.clearRect(0,0,k.width,k.height),l.fillText(c.apply(this,a),0,0); var d=k.toDataURL(); l.clearRect(0,0,k.width,k.height),l.fillText(c.apply(this,b),0,0); var e=k.toDataURL(); return d===e } function e(a) { var b; if(!l||!l.fillText)return!1; switch(l.textBaseline="top",l.font="600 32px Arial",a) { case"flag":return!(b=d([55356,56826,55356,56819],[55356,56826,8203,55356,56819]))%26%26(b=d([55356,57332,56128,56423,56128,56418,56128,56421,56128,56430,56128,56423,56128,56447],[55356,57332,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56418,8203,56128,56421,8203,56128,56430,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56447]),!b); case"emoji":return b=d([55358,56760,9792,65039],[55358,56760,8203,9792,65039]),!b } return!1 } function f(a) { var c=b.createElement("script"); c.src=a,c.defer=c.type="text/javascript",b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c) } var g,h,i,j,k=b.createElement("canvas"),l=k.getContext%26%26k.getContext("2d"); for(j=Array("flag","emoji"),c.supports= { everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0 } ,i=0; i]]

Need to find the script location to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just... leave it.

It's default WordPress Javascript that make your [emoji](https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) beautier. The script can be found at WordPress official website: https://twentyfourteendemo.wordpress.com

In case you want to remove it, install a plugin called [Disable WP Emoji Icons](https://vi.wordpress.org/plugins/disable-wp-emoji-icons/).

Comment: My Username and password is changing by someone. How to identify that?. Please help.